# Does aurelia work with nesting in iOS and Android apps?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, aurelia

I've heard tale that you can nest/package/frame javascript in an android or iOS app. I've been told once that this is only possible through react native, but I'm faced with a task of turning an aurelia app into a mobile app. Can it be done like this? Or am I looking at redesigning most of the app?

Comment: I thought Aurelia apps could be deployed as iOS apps. Is this not true?

Comment: How would one do this?

Comment: You can do this just like a normal app in browser, have you tried it?